# Secure Cookies in ASP.NET not adding a secure Flag

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies

I have created a asp.net project
  Created a new HTTPCookie,i want to add a secure flag to it when my connect is secure
Below is my Code

```
var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(Test)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Value = asdasdhoi234
        };
        if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            responseCookie.Secure = true;
        }
       Response.Cookies.Set(Test);
```

But the cookie is still not secure ,i am not understanding the problem.

In my httpsHeaders it still does not show my secure cookies
My domain is https but still my cookies are not secure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`new HttpCookie` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a string as an argument. Hence I suppose your `Test` is a string. You need to set the `Secure` flag on an actual cookie object and not a string. Try this:

```
var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(Test)
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Value = "asdasdhoi234",
    Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection
};
Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
```

Also, please make sure that your web.config contains `requireSSL` attribute set to true as stated in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>   <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
>     cookieless="UseCookies"
>     requireSSL="true"
>     path="/MyApplication" />
> </authentication>
> ```

Comment: Sorry for that it was a typo i have set the flag on actual object,Please check my updated question

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte Please check if `FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL` is true (which requires update in your web.config)

Comment: I dont have this code in web.config,but i dont inderstand while i am debugging` FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection`  it is true even though my local connection is not secure.

Comment: Is it necessary to add FormsAuthentication validation for secure cookies?

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte In my opinion no. As long as session is secure itself it should be fine. Hence `Secure = Request.IsSecureConnection` should be sufficient. But of course depends on your needs.